# What do I do with downloaded FsLab template?

Tags: f#, nuget, paket, fslab

Sorry for the question, but I am definitely not an "advanced" user.

I installed the `FsLab` and `FsLab Journal` using `NuGet`.

The instructions in https://fslab.org/download/ tell one to `Download FsLab Journal template` (which I did, and got a folder called  `FsLab.Templates-journal` on my desktop). Next there is a link saying `Install Visual Studio template`. If I click on that I go to a page in the `Visual Studio Marketplace` with the title `FsLab Journal` and a green `Download` button. When I click on that button nothing happens. On the same page it says `FsLab Journal` works with Visual Studio 2012, 2013 and 2015. (Does it work with VS 2017?)

I would like to use `FsLab` and `FsLab Journal` to interactively see tables and charts in FSI. I hope `FsLab Journal` will help me do that but right now I am stuck and do not know what to do with the folder I downloaded (inside a zip file). Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you are going to need to unzip the folder, then open the .fsproj file with visual studio.

Go to the .paket folder, run paket.bootstrapper.exe

Go to the root folder, run build.cmd

Open Tutorial.fsx, select everything, right click -> Execute in interactive window.

Comment: Thanks. I did that but got the message "error FS0078: Unable to find the file 'packages/FsLab/Themes/DefaultWhite.fsx' in any of
 C:\Users\Soldalma\Desktop\FsLab.Templates-journal" in `FSI`. In the Error List there are additional messages about FsLab.fsx, Deedle, XPlot, Series. I checked and I do have a `DefaultWhite.fsx` in a solution called FsLabTest I created but that file is not in the folder  `FsLab.Templates-journal`

Comment: Whoops, apologies for that, I had replicated the process using FsLabBasic template, not journals, see the edit for the missing two steps

Comment: Thanks again. Before I go ahead and do as you suggested, I noticed that the .sln and the .fsproj files are in the same folder. When I create a project in VS 2017 normally the .fsproj is in a subfolder of the folder where the .sln project is. Will it be a problem if both files are in the same folder? Normally the folders where my .sln files are are subfolders of another folder I called VSProjects (perhaps I should have called it VSSolutions). Should I copy the FsLab.Templates-journal to my VSProjects folder? Or should I create another layer: VSProjects\FsLab\FsLab.Templates-journal?

Comment: In any case, I tried what you suggested in the folder located under my desktop and it worked fine. The whole Tutorial.fsx ran in FSI and I got a chart on my browser. This did not look that different from the usual FSI experience. I also opened the solution in VS 2017 and tried to run Runner.fs but I got a message "Error:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'FSharp.Markdown, Version=2.14.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies."

Comment: I can confirm the .fs crashes, ... holy moly that is one crazy build script. I would reccomend just copying the code from Tutorial.fsx into a new project, and Install-Package FsLab